# i want to find a specific peiece of data from a string using python regular expresion and exclude specific portion

Tags: regex, web-scraping, regular-language

`((http(s?):)./([a-z]).*/)` This is regular expression is try

but in this string i want directory like this: **/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/**

And the image name like this :  **VideoHive-Happy-Kids-Slideshow-Premiere-Pro-MOGRT-Free-Download-GetintoPC.com_-300x169.jpg**

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 capture groups

```
https?:\/\/[^/]*(\/wp-content\/uploads\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/)([^\/\s]+)
```

- `https?:\/\/[^/]*` Match the protocol to before the first `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\/wp-content\/uploads\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/` Match `/wp-content/uploads/` 4 digits `/` 2 digits `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `([^\/\s]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ time any char except `/` or a whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JXtIjl/1)

```js
const s = `https://getintopc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/VideoHive-Happy-Kids-Slideshow-Premiere-Pro-MOGRT-Free-Download-GetintoPC.com_-300x169.jpg https://getintopc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/VideoHive-Happy-Kids-Slideshow-Premiere-Pro-MOGRT-Direct-Link-Free-Download-GetintoPC.com_-300x169.jpg https://getintopc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/VideoHive-Happy-Kids-Slideshow-Premiere-Pro-MOGRT-Full-Offline-Installer-Free-Download-GetintoPC.com_-300x169.jpg https://getintopc.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/VideoHive-Happy-Kids-Slideshow-Premiere-Pro-MOGRT-Latest-Version-Free-Download-GetintoPC.com_-300x169.jpg`;
const regex = /https?:\/\/[^/]*(\/wp-content\/uploads\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/)([^\/\s]+)/g;
const res = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1], m[2]]);
console.log(res);
```

Or a bit broader version, first matching folders starting with `[a-z]` followed by folders starting with a digit and ending the last part on for example `.jpg`

```
https?:\/\/[^/]*((?:\/[a-z][^/]*)+(?:\/\d+)+\/)([^\/]+\.jpg)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qZVRX/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
https?:\/\/.*?(?<folder>\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/)(?<image>.*)
```

I have added two capturing groups, by the names of folder and image.